# Which version of 2sxc content module is stable and has correct references in source code, so that it can be deployed and launched locally?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dnn9

I need to deploy and launch 2sxc module source code locally on my pc. Which release version is stable and has correct references? I tried it with version 11.05.00, but didn't succeed so far.

Answer (score 0):

What problems did you find, and which version of DNN are you using?

I have 2sxc 11.4.0 running in a DNN 9.7.2 installation.  No problems.

Looking at GitHub, I see 11.07.01 for LTS and a couple of "minor bugfix" releases following it.  It looks like I should consider updating ...

Answer (score 0):

Basically almost all releases are stable - and we recommend LTS releases.

I don't understand what you mean with `correct references` - could you elaborate?

Comment: I mansioned references, because when I followed your instructions I tried to connect 2sxc source code to existing DNN website, which has different path and url locally on my pc. So something went wrong and at first EAV projects were not found, so I added them manually. And after that I had like 1k+ compile errors with namespaces problems including projects and nuget packages refs. So I wonder if there's version, which has correct  relative path refs, so that it works in any directory with any url.

Comment: P.S. I'm using DNN v.9.6.1, visual studio 2019 (v.16.3.9).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I tried to connect 2sxc source code to existing DNN website."

Did you download an installable zip file for 2sxc and then install it as a module?

If you are playing games with DNN and 2sxc source code, you need to back up and do some reading to understand how to install DNN and then install extensions like 2sxc.  No source code is needed.  In fact, is it un-recommended.

Comment: I just read this and find the statements and question(s) very confusing. Can you please start over and provide context? What are the steps that lead up to "but didn't succeed"? Provide a link to "I followed your instructions"? What type of connection and is it front-end of server-side? Are you possibly in Visually Studio and trying to get your own customized version of 2sxc to compile?? Is this WebApi related?